# Number of returned values

Tags: lua, return-value

I've got a function which is returning a bunch of values and I can't know how many arguments are returned.

```
function ascii( value )
[...]
    if type( value ) == "string" then
      if #value > 1 then
        local temp = {}
        for i = 1, #value do
          table.insert( temp , (value:byte(i)) )
        end
        return unpack( temp ) --<-- unknown number of return values
      else
        return value:byte(1)
      end
    end
[...]
end
```

How can I know how many values are returned?

My first idea was this:

```
return numberOfValues, unpack( temp )
```

But in most cases, the number of values is irrelevant. 
Is there a way to get around that extra effort which is unnecessary in 95% of all cases?

Comment: Please do not discuss the reasonableness of such an ascii function, thats not the point. Not to offend you, but there are some people that love doing this ;-) It could by any other function that returns an unpacked table.

Comment: It's not clear what your asking. What's wrong with your original code? What is the "extra effort" you're trying to get rid of?

Comment: The question is, how to know how many values are returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your function definition as it is and call it like this:

```
local values = {ascii(myString)}
local n = #values
```

Comment: Obfuscation at its finest :D

Comment: This doesn't work in the general case when `ascii` return values include `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Number of returned values is not the same as the number of elements in the table built from returned values. It works in the example you have, but only because the example doesn't include any `nil` values.

In the general case when the returned values may include `nil`, it's almost always better to use `select('#'...)` instead:

```
print(#{(function() return 1, nil, 2 end)()})
print(select('#', (function() return 1, nil, 2 end)()))
```

This code prints `1 3` in Lua 5.1, but `3 3` in Lua 5.2 and Lua 5.3. Adding one more `nil` to the return values changes this to `1 4` under all these versions of Lua.

These functions can be used as wrappers that returns the number of return values and also return a list or a table with the values:

```
function wrap(...) return select('#', ...), ... end
function wrapt(...) return select('#', ...), {...} end
```

Using one of these functions, `print(wrap((function() return 1, nil, 2, nil end)()))` prints `4 1 nil 2 nil` as expected.